# To get character equivalent of number in c

Tags: c

I have a string which has this:

```
((12+41)*30)
```

here `12`, `41` and `30` are all characters. How do I do arithmetic operations on them ?

Also when I have a number `20` how can I get a string which reads 20?

Comment: You need an expression parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to calculate expressions like that you need create a tree of the tokens 12, +, 41, 30

```
                  *
                /   \
             [+]    30
            /   \
          12     41
```

this can be done for instance by converting your infix expression to a postfix expression, by doing so the correct operator precedence can be set. Then you go through the tree using a stack to evaluate the expression.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question, read about [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). To convert int to string use sprintf().

```
char *string[256];
int n = 100;
sprintf(string, "%d", n);
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first question, if you want to do this properly, you'll need to generate a parser for the sort of expressions you want.  Read about [bison](http://www.gnu.org/s/bison/) -- in fact [section 2.2 of the manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/bison/manual/html_node/Infix-Calc.html) is about writing a parser for just such expressions as the ones you give here.

Obtaining a parser this way is Doing It Properly, though I won't claim it's particularly easy (learning about bison is a bit mind-bending, the first time).  It'll be possible to hack together a parser by hand, but it'll take longer in the end, and not be in the least bit educational.  Once you know how to use tools like bison, you can reuse that knowledge in all sorts of places.